# Nginx + PageSpeed: first request fingerprinting

Tags: nginx, pagespeed

Scenario:

1. Delete PageSpeed cache (e.g. on source version update)
2. Send request to Nginx
3. Get response HTML

Expected:

Every link in HTML will be with fingerprint, e.g. "filename.pagespeed.232dsfsf3343.js"

The Problem:

Right after I delete PageSpeed cache, I see that html returned from **first** request is missing fingerprints (or, sometimes, only part of files returned without fingerprints).

It looks like PageSpeed rebuilds its cache, abd that process is asynchronious. So, if there is a request while PageSpeed builds its cache - the request isn't delayed and returned as is - even if it without fingerprints.

Is there any way to delay response, until PageSpeed cache constructed?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is some way to delay response. BUT this solution has some risks.
At first you need to enable InPlaceResourceOptimization:

```
Apache:
ModPagespeedInPlaceResourceOptimization on
Nginx:
pagespeed InPlaceResourceOptimization on;
```

Then you need to specify maximum delay

```
Apache:
ModPagespeedInPlaceRewriteDeadlineMs deadline_value_in_milliseconds
Nginx:
pagespeed InPlaceRewriteDeadlineMs deadline_value_in_milliseconds;
```

> When InPlaceResourceOptimization is enabled, PageSpeed uses a default deadline of 10ms the when optimizing the resource. If the optimization cannot be completed in 10ms, then the original resource is served to the client, while the optimization continues in the background. Once cached, the optimized resource will be served for further requests. Note that a value less than zero will cause PageSpeed to wait indefinitely.

As you see by-effect of this approach that client still can download non-optimized content, if its optimization can not be completed before the deadline

Also I found such record in resolved issues of pagespeed:

> [Issue 871](https://github.com/pagespeed/mod_pagespeed/issues/871) Apply in-place optimization on first request if InPlaceRewriteDeadlineMs is -1 and LoadFromFile is enabled.